# Trigger right-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am trying to late-bind context menus to elements, using the [ContextMenu plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/). So on the first right-click on those elements, I would like to :

1. intercept the right-click through a live event on a certain "uncontextmenued" class,
2. determine if the `data('events').contextmenu` exists,
3. if not, attach the context-menu (and change the class to avoid re-throwing this live process),
4. re-throw the right-click event to show the right-click.

I'm having trouble with the last item. jQuery allows to `.click()` or to `.trigger('click')`, which simulate a left-click, but there seems not to be a way to fire a right-click event through `trigger`.

Or is there?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can trigger it by

```
$('#element').trigger({
    type: 'mousedown',
    which: 3
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#example-5

Comment: Ok that put me on the right track. Just to complete the answer, the quoted plugin actually needs a mousedown followed by a mouseup... So triggering like Niclas said must be followed by a trigger('mouseup'). Since it's the 'button' property, and not the 'which' property which is read by the plugin, the actual answer to my problem was $('#element').trigger('mousedown',{button:2}).trigger('mouseup') . Thanks Niclas.

Comment: Hi subtenante, one million thanks, I was after just the same functionality and your answer really helped me a lot, but I think you have an error there, I had to change it to:
$('#element').trigger({type:'mousedown',button:2}).trigger({type:'mouseup'}); 
to make it work.

Comment: The same in my case, "mouseup" instead of "mousedown".

Comment: This does not work for me. I also tried the solution Ben Lesh provided without success. ?

Answer (score 10):

There is a newer way to do this:

```
$('#element').triggerHandler('contextmenu');
```

[Documentation can be found here](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

Comment: For me the `'contextMenu'` didn't work. Instead, `'contextmenu'` worked properly.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to this, but I'm not sure if you may be referring to jQuery UI data, but.

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) 
{
    if(event.which == 3)
    {
        if(typeof($(this).data('events')) === 'undefined')
        {
            $(this).data('events', { somedata: 'hello' });
        }
        else
        {
            // "re-throw" right click context menu
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want to trigger a right-click event, not attach an event to it.