# How to trigger contextmenu on left mouse button click?

Tags: jquery, click, contextmenu, eventtrigger

I'm trying to use contextmenu for the left menu button click but it's not working:

```
<input type="button" id="selector"  value="click" />
```

jquery:

```
$('#selector').on('click',function(){
 $(this).triggerHandler('contextmenu')   
});
```

How should I implement?

Please check this is not working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5dAL/)

Please note: I want to use default contextmenu on left click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250447/trigger-right-click

Comment: not working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q5dAL/

Comment: http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/trigger-left-click.html - I cannot get it working either using triggerHandler

Comment: Did you used any event handler for right click?

Comment: no, I just want to trigger right click (contextmenu) on left click.

Comment: Then, what you expect on right click? triggerHandler works. http://jsfiddle.net/GGp64/1/

Comment: @Satpal when you use right click you'll see context menus and I want to show the default context menu in left click

Answer (score 3):

If you are using contextmenu plugin then you can simply use trigger: 'left' for left button click.

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        trigger: 'left',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
        }
    });
});
```

You can find plugin details and documentation from [click here](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/trigger-left-click.html) link

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/Q5dAL/1/)
You no need to trigger event, [contextMenu](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html) can be shown [manually](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#show-trigger).

```
$( function( windowLoadE ) {
    $( "#selector" ).on( "click", function( clickE ) {
        $( this ).contextMenu( { x: clickE.offsetX, y: clickE.offsetY } );
    } );
    $.contextMenu( {
        selector: "#selector", 
        callback: function( key, options ) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log( m ) || alert( m ); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
            "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
            "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
            "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
            "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Or use [trigger option](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#options) to handle left click.

Comment: @RahulSonwanshiI just set jQuery 2.1.3 version

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document) .bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
  e.preventdefault();
  if (event.which == 1) {
    $('#menu') .css({
      top: e.pageY + 'px',
      left: e.pageX + 'px'
    }) .show();
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You can not open browser default context menu on left Click , You should either Make Your Own one or just add some simple list :)

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript doesn't have the power to open the default browser context menu.

However, you can catch `contextmenu` event and trigger `contextmenu` event on simple click:

```
$('#selector').on('click', function () {
    $(this).triggerHandler('contextmenu');
}).on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    alert('foo');
});
```

Comment: but its not opening context menu